# iterating through folders

Tags: javascript, html, iteration

I have a list of items all of which are wrapped with a div, and each item is inside a `<p>` tag. 
I need to add an

```
<a href="../Filepath/Followed by, in numerical order, 7.html ---> all the way through infinity.
```

So for instance if I have 100 items all with a

```
<p>
```

tag, then I want a matching number of

```
<a href>
```

tags to be generated.

I thought a loop would be a nice solution, but cant come up with the scheme to make it work.

I did start on the code, and this is what i have come up with so far.
Keep in mind that I am storing all the html files in a folder which I access via the script. All of which are numbered from 7 ++ ...

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
<p>Textual description of item</p> 
...
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var files = {'.html':100};
var pageName = "";
var html = "", src;
for (var ext in files){
for (var i = 0; i < files[ext]; i++){
     src = "../Filepath/[i]/" + pageName + "-" + (i+1) + "." + ext;
     html += '<a href="'+src+'"></a>';
}

$("container").prepend(html);
}});
```

(The script is not finished, so feel free to alter it completely if you have a better approach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line

```
src = "../Filepath/[i]/" + pageName + "-" + (i+1) + "." + ext;
```

supposed to be

```
src = "../Filepath/[" +i + "]/" + pageName + "-" + (i+1) + "." + ext;
```

Comment: How does the src look like when rendered in HTML